# warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable not found (when installing jasperreport server on centos)

Tags: centos6, jasperserver

I want to start jasper report server in terminal;
but when i enter **"./js-install-ce.sh"** command in terminal below warnings Is shown.
please guide me to solve this error.
(os: centos6 , jasper report server: jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
WARNING: JAVA_HOME environment variable not found
[default]

### Running install-normal-ce Ant task.

Buildfile: /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0-bin/buildomatic/build.xml
     [echo]

Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)
     [echo]

chkIfPackageManagedTomcat: check if package managed tomcat
BUILD FAILED

/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0-bin/buildomatic/build.xml:61: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/setup.xml:757: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/setup.xml:543: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/setup.xml:744: /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0-bin/buildomatic/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/lib does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command to check if you have java installed

`java -version`

Something like below will appear as output

`java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)`

If you don't get any output or command not found or something like, you'll need to install Java.
Download from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

and extract as following.

`tar xzf jdk-7u79-linux-i586.tar.gz`

You'll get the Java directory extracted.

If you have Java already installed then you just need to find it's home directory.

Now set the environment variable JAVA_HOME.

`export JAVA_HOME=path to java directory`
`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH`

These environment variables will become active in the current login session of your console.
If you want to add them permanently then you can add the same lines, in the 
**.bashrc** file in your home directory.

Now your install should work.

Comment: after setting environment variables,and  echo command                            "echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre"                                                                                  there are that warning when i am starting jasperreport in terminal.                                                                                                     WARNING: JAVA_HOME environment variable not found
[default]